# how to get content from Share dialog in NET MAUI desktop application?

Tags: android, .net-maui

i know how to configure the plataform windows package manifest for subscribe app as Share target but i dont know how get share content into net MAUI

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnj2z.jpg

i register this behaviour in `Package.appxmanifest` under Windows folder inside Plataforms

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TyMW.jpg

on android intent event can archive this `onCreate` function (https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive), what method or event need to catch for get content in Share dialog under Windows Desktop app for Net MAUI? any advice will be appreciate

Comment: For the uwp, there is a api `OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)` to receive it. But for the maui , I can't find the official docuemnt about this, you can report it to the github.

Answer (score 0):

1. At first it might be better to disable multi-instances of your MAUI app in Windows. Here is the sample of possible modifications of your app: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9973.
2. Redirect all activation events to your handlers. Like in the sample above:

```
//Getting events
var args = AppInstance.GetCurrent().GetActivatedEventArgs();

//Creating your own handler
 ---> keyInstance.Activated += OnActivated;
and redirect events
---> await keyInstance.RedirectActivationToAsync(args);
```

3. Handling "Share" events. I've created the sample that handles Share event from Paint 3D to mine MAUI app. I've used MAUI Dependency services to simplify image proceeding on the side of main app logic:

Here are the updates in Program.cs:

```
 private static void OnActivated(object sender, AppActivationArguments args)
    {
        if (app is null)
        {
            throw new Exception("app should not be null");
        }

        //here is the sample how we could simply use MAUI Dependency Service for our purposes (see declarations in MauiProgram.cs)
        var imageTransportService = app.Services.GetService(typeof(IImagePickerService)) as IImagePickerService;
        if (imageTransportService is null)
            return;

        if (args?.Kind != ExtendedActivationKind.ShareTarget)
            return;

        var sharedArgs = args.Data as ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs;
        if (sharedArgs == null)
            return;

        //Sharing number of files 
        //3D Paint share pictures in this way
        if (sharedArgs.ShareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                sharedArgs.ShareOperation.ReportStarted();
                IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> storageItems = null;
                storageItems = await sharedArgs.ShareOperation.Data.GetStorageItemsAsync();
                string fileList = String.Empty;

                List<Stream> imageStreamList = new();
                for (int index = 0; index < storageItems.Count; index++)
                {
                    var storageItem = storageItems[index] as StorageFile;
                    if (storageItem == null) continue;

                    if (HasImageExtension(storageItem.Name))
                    {
                        Stream imageStream = null;
                        try
                        {
                            var randomAccessStream = await storageItem.OpenReadAsync();
                            imageStream = randomAccessStream.AsStreamForRead();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) { continue; }

                        imageStreamList.Add(imageStream);
                    }
                    else { continue; }//some other format that we do not consider
                }

                if (imageStreamList.Count > 1)
                {
                    imageTransportService.RizeImagesStream(imageStreamList);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (imageStreamList.Count == 1)
                        imageTransportService.RizeImageStream(imageStreamList[0]);
                }

                sharedArgs.ShareOperation.ReportCompleted();
            });
            return;
        }
        else //Bitmap 
             //Probably some other app could share bitmap in this way
             //I was disappointed that 3D Paint do not share picture in this way :(
        if (sharedArgs.ShareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Bitmap))
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                sharedArgs.ShareOperation.ReportStarted();

                var randomStream = await sharedArgs.ShareOperation.Data.GetBitmapAsync();
                var resultStream = await randomStream.OpenReadAsync();

                imageTransportService .RizeImageStream(resultStream.AsStreamForRead());

                //Getting image on other side:
                //var image = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => resultStream.AsStream()) };

                sharedArgs.ShareOperation.ReportCompleted();

            });
            return;
        }
        //else //Text
        //if (sharedArgs.ShareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
        //{
        //}
        //else
        //    if (sharedArgs.ShareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Uri))
        //{ 
        //    //proceed uri
        //}
        //else
        //    if (sharedArgs.ShareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.ApplicationLink))
        //{
        //    //proceed app link
        //}
        //else
        //    if (sharedArgs.ShareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.WebLink))
        //{
        //    //proceed weblink
        //}
        //else
        //    if (sharedArgs.ShareOperation.Data.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Html))
        //{
        //    //proceed html
        //}
    }

    public static bool HasImageExtension(string pathOrExt)
    {
        // ext = "*.bmp;*.dib;*.rle"           descr = BMP
        // ext = "*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe;*.jfif"   descr = JPEG
        // ext = "*.gif"                       descr = GIF
        // ext = "*.tif;*.tiff"                descr = TIFF
        // ext = "*.png"   
        var source = Path.GetExtension(pathOrExt).ToLower();
        
        return 
            (source.EndsWith(".png") || //common case ->ths why the first
             source.EndsWith(".bmp") || 
             source.EndsWith(".dib") ||
             source.EndsWith(".rle") ||
             source.EndsWith(".jpg") ||
             source.EndsWith(".jpeg") ||
             source.EndsWith(".jpe") ||
             source.EndsWith(".jfif") ||
             source.EndsWith(".gif") ||
             source.EndsWith(".tif") ||
             source.EndsWith(".tiff"));
    }
```

Modification of MauiProgram.cs to support some new "shared images transport" services.

```
public static class MauiProgram
{
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });


        // Registering our service here -->
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IImagePickerService>(new ImagePickerService());
        //registering your app pages and services
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
        //builder.Services.AddTransient<SomeOtherPage>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}

//Some prototypes of "shared images transport" service
public interface IImagePickerService
{

    public delegate void ImagePass(object sender, Stream imageStream);
    public event ImagePass OnPickImage;

    public delegate void ImagesPass(object sender, List<Stream> imageStreams);
    public event ImagesPass OnPickImages;

    public void RizeImageStream(Stream imageStream);
    public void RizeImagesStream(List<Stream> imageStreams);
}

public class ImagePickerService : IImagePickerService
{
    public event IImagePickerService.ImagePass OnPickImage;
    public event IImagePickerService.ImagesPass OnPickImages;

    public void RizeImageStream(Stream imageStream)
    {
        OnPickImage?.Invoke(this, imageStream);
    }

    public void RizeImagesStream(List<Stream> imageStreams)
    {
        OnPickImages?.Invoke(this, imageStreams);
    }
}
```

And the last one. On the side of main logic (in my example MainPage.xaml.cs) you could sibscribe to shared data events:

```
  //..some declarations here
IImagePickerService imagePicker;
  //Thanks MAUI dependecy services mechanism for automatic providing our "shared images transport" registered service -->
  public MainPage(IImagePickerService imagePicker)
    {
       //.. some code here
        _imagePicker = imagePicker;
        _imagePicker.OnPickImage += OnPickImage;
        _imagePicker.OnPickImages += OnPickImages;

        InitializeComponent();
        
       //.. some code here
    }

    private void OnPickImages(object sender, List<Stream> imageStreams)
    {
        List<Image> images = new List<Image>();
        foreach(var imageStream in imageStreams)
        {
            images.Add(new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => imageStream) });
        }

        //some usage of shared images
    }

    private void OnPickImage(object sender, Stream imageStream)
    {
        Image image = new Image { Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => imageStream) };
        //some usage of shared image
    }
```

Perhaps there is some more convenient way. I've just show you where you could find events and how you should proceed the data. It's quite untrivial way of ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs proceeding.

The second thing is that the image that was passed to the app in my case (paint 3D) has some incorrects in rgb channels. It could be easily corrected on the step of image postprocessing but I think Microsoft should do this job on their side.

PS: And dont forget that ImageSource.FromFile(()=> {}) doesnt work for now (may,23/ Microsoft bug), so you'll not see the image on the page if you'll organize better way of image tranport to your app (like file or share path). Anyway you'll need to use stream.

---

PS2: I have also created a sample of **Android** support. Unfortunatelly it was more complicated for me due to lack of appropriate documentation.

I added IntentFilter for sharing support as a sample to understand how you could manage different types. And also used MAUI Dependency mechanism from previous sample to show how we can proceed image data from MainActivity to some other places in our app.

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density),
LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSend, Intent.ActionSend, Intent.ActionSendMultiple },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryDefault },
    DataMimeTypes = new[] { "image/*", "text/plain", "image/*"})]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
     protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        
        string action = intent.Action;
        string type = intent.Type;
        if (Intent.ActionSend.Equals(action) && type != null)
        {
            if (type.Equals("text/plain"))
            {
                ProceedText(intent);
            }
            else
            if (type.StartsWith("image/"))
            {
                ProceedImage(intent);
            }
        }
        else
        if (Intent.ActionSendMultiple.Equals(action) && type != null)
        {
            if (type.StartsWith("image/"))
            {
                ProceedMultipleImages(intent);
            }

        }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
 

        if (Intent == null) return;

        string action = Intent.Action;
        string type = Intent.Type;
        if (Intent.ActionSend.Equals(action) && type != null)
        {
            if (type.Equals("text/plain"))
            {
                ProceedText(Intent);
            }
            else
            if (type.StartsWith("image/"))
            {
                ProceedImage(Intent);
            }
        } 
        else
        if (Intent.ActionSendMultiple.Equals(action) && type != null)
        {
            if(type.StartsWith("image/"))
                ProceedMultipleImages(Intent);
        }
    }


    private void ProceedMultipleImages(Intent intent)
    {
        var imagePickerService = MauiApplication.Current?.Services?.GetService(typeof(IImagePickerService)) as IImagePickerService;
        if (imagePickerService == null) { return; }

        var clipData = intent.ClipData;

        if (clipData != null)
        {
            List<Stream> streams = new List<Stream>();

            for (int i = 0; i < clipData.ItemCount; i++)
            {
                ClipData.Item item = clipData.GetItemAt(i);
                Android.Net.Uri uri = item.Uri;
                Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri);
                if(stream == null) {
                    continue;
                }
                streams.Add(stream);
            }
            if(streams.Count > 0)
            {
                imagePickerService.RizeImagesStream(streams);
            }


        }
    }

    private void ProceedImage(Intent intent)
    {
        var imagePickerService = MauiApplication.Current?.Services?.GetService(typeof(IImagePickerService)) as IImagePickerService;
        if (imagePickerService == null) { return; }

        var clipData = intent.ClipData;

        if (clipData?.ItemCount == 0) return;
        
        ClipData.Item item = clipData.GetItemAt(0);
        Android.Net.Uri uri = item.Uri;


            Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri);
        if (stream == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        imagePickerService.RizeImageStream(stream);
    }

    private void ProceedText(Intent intent)
    {
        var imagePickerService = MauiApplication.Current?.Services?.GetService(typeof(IImagePickerService)) as IImagePickerService;
        if (imagePickerService == null) { return; }

        //do the same as in previous (add to IImagePickerService -> text handlers) and proceed text through it
//..
    }
```

The key things that you should consider are:

1. You should set **LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask**. In this case the default handler of incoming sharing data is **OnNewIntent** method. Otherwise (except SingleTop) the default handler will be OnCreate method => in this case you'll get additional instance of you app. That's not a problem for correct handling on our side but there is a bug on Microsoft GUI side in such kind of app initialization (SetColors method =>MAUI theme initialization).
2. You should dublicate the logic for share data processing at **OnCreate** method too. If your app is stopped and some other app launch your app by sharing to you some data - the default handler will be OnCreate method... In this case all initializations will be correct.
3. I also show the sample here how you could get access from droid side to MAUI dependency mechanism: **MauiApplication.Current?.Services?.GetService**(typeof(IImagePickerService)) as IImagePickerService;